# Passing hidden values from html to ajax safely

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

this might be newbie question.
so i have a disabled vat input, i have made a hidden one to pass the vat to form submit..

```
<input type="text" name="vat[]" id="vat_1" class="form-control" disabled autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="vat_value[]" id="vat_value_1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

then i calculate the total etc with Jquery..
any one can change it from the console any other secure way ?

Comment: There are a few ways in which hackers can bypass your code this is why server-side validation of user input is vital. You also need to ensure that the data isn't negative quantity values, product codes are correct and the correct taxes are calculated - all on the server-side of your application. Also you need to check for any sql injection attempts.

Comment: If you do not want Users to modify this content, do not let it appear client side. IF you're posting it back, anyone could make their own HTTP POST and modify the value. As was mentioned, server side scripting will be desired, and you can make use of Session variables to store and track User data that the User cannot access.

Answer (score 0):

You can set session variables...

```html
//=== YourForm.php ===
<?php
session_start();

//Set a variable
$_SESSION['myVar']="MyValue";
?>

//=== YourSubmissionScript.php ===
<?php
session_start();

//Retrieve the variable
$myimportedvar=$_SESSION['myVar'];

//Use the variable...
?>
```

Read more about session variables [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

Of course, you didnt included code within your question, which makes it hard to help you, to give you a more in-depth answer that is more relevant to your problem.

Good luck!